# Expansion of macros within chemmacros' \ch{} macro

Tags: macros, expansion, chemmacros

I have some chemical formulae throughout my whole text that are changed from time to time. So I defined a macro `\compound` with the approporiate content for usage in `chemmacros'` `\ch` macro.

Compiling the document (see MWE) shows that the direct entry works as expected (is typeset as a formula), while the second version is typeset as normal text.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\newcommand{\compound}{H2O}

\begin{document}
Works: \ch{H2O}
Does not work: \ch{\compound}
\end{document}
```

Do I miss (or misunderstand) something?

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\ch` is *not* provided by `chemmacros` but by the `chemformula` package.

As you've noticed it doesn't expand its argument. As a consequence when it sees `\compound` (unaware of its definition) it does nothing with it and just inputs it. Only afterwards `\compound` expands to its definition but then it is too late.

That means you either need to do that manually by adding the appropriate number of `\expandafter`s or you can define a `\chX` (say) which expands its argument once before parsing it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \chX { O{}m }
  { \chemformula_ch:no {#1} {#2} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \chemformula_ch:nn {no}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\compound}{H2O}

\begin{document}

\ch{H2O} \par
\expandafter\ch\expandafter{\compound} \par
\chX{\compound}

\end{document}
```

If you choose the `\chX` way together with `chemmacros` you either should also load `chemformula` explicitly (`\usepackage{chemmacros}\usepackage{chemformula}`) or tell `chemformula` to do it for you (`\chemsetup{formula = chemformula}`) before defining the variant.